# How to change the border color of a Grouped UITableView

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.2

This concerns iPhoneOS-sdk-3.2

I am having difficulty changing the border color of a grouped UITableView.  I can change the cell background color, separator color, text color, quite easily now, and the rounded corners clip correctly, even when highlighted with whatever colors I have chosen. However the surrounding border remains infuriatingly gray despite many different attempts.

I have read all of the related posts I can find via Google, let alone stackoverflow. I have seen Mike Akers' heroic PITA solution for UITableViewCell clipping -- this problem is solved for iPhoneOS 3.0 and it did not help me with the border.

I have tried both a programmatic and xib-based solution and both provide the same results.

I will share the programmatic version below:

I have a UIViewController subclass rather than a UITableViewController subclass to act as a UITableView delegate -- I chose this route as I am coding on the iPad and UITableViewController reportedly takes over the whole screen.  loadView method of my UIViewController subclass:

```
- (void) loadView {
  self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
  [self.view release];
  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

  // add and configure UITableView                                                                                     
  CGRect tableViewRect = CGRectMake(0., 0., 256., 768.);

  myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableViewRect style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

  // set the tableview delegate to this object and the datasource to the datasource which has already been set          
  myTableView.delegate = self;
  myTableView.dataSource = self;

  myTableView.sectionIndexMinimumDisplayRowCount = 1;

  myTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  myTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  myTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;

  myTableView.opaque = NO;

  // add the table view to our background view                                                                          
  [self.view addSubview:myTableView];
  [myTableView release];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution.  This behavior does appear to be iPhoneOS 3.2 specific as Apple added a  backgroundView property for UITableView in iPhoneOS 3.2.

I tried [myTableView.backgroundView removeFromSuperView] and UITableView just replaced it with another.

Instead, my solution was to add:

`myTableView.backgroundView.hidden = YES;`

Comment: Worked for me. I still wonder why setting the background view to non opaque and its color to clearColor didn't work, but won't spend any more time on it.